# Spring boot rabbitmq no exchange '"xxxxxxx"' in vhost '/'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm writing a simple rabbitmq producer with spring boot 2.2.7.

On the broker side I've setup a **direct exchange** *samples* , a **queue** named *samples.default* and binded them together adding a *samples.default* **bindkey key**.

when running the application I get the following error

```
Attempting to connect to: [127.0.0.1:5672]
2020-05-14 15:13:39.232  INFO 28393 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#2f860823:0/SimpleConnection@3946e760 [delegate=amqp://open-si@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 34710]
2020-05-14 15:13:39.267 ERROR 28393 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange '"samples"' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

The rabbitmq server configuration is correct as I've a python producer that already puts messages succesfully in the "samples.default" queue.

in Spring boot I'm using jackson serialization, but that's not the prolem here I think as I've tested the code without the Jakson serialization configuration and the problem is still the same.

My broker configuration is set both in the **application.properties** :

```
#spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=xxxx
spring.rabbitmq.password=xxxx

broker.exchange = "samples"
broker.routingKey = "samples.default"
```

*note that using spring.rabbitmq.host doesn't work as it results in using my internet provider address* !

and in a **BrokerConf** configuration class :

```
@Configuration
public class BrokerConf {

    @Bean("publisher")
    MessagePublisher<BaseSample> baseSamplePublisher(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return new MessagePublisher<BaseSample>(rabbitTemplate);
    }


    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final var rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

The publisher base class is as :

```
@Component
public class MessagePublisher<T> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessagePublisher.class);
    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public MessagePublisher(RabbitTemplate r) {
        rabbitTemplate = r;
    }

    public void publish(List<BaseSample> messages, String exchange, String routingKey) {
            for (BaseSample message: messages) {
                rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingKey, message);
            }
    }

}
```

that I use in a rest controller

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SamplesController.class);
@Autowired
private MessagePublisher<BaseSample> publisher;

@Value("${broker.exchange}")
private String exchange;
@Value("${broker.routingKey}")
private String routingKey;


@PutMapping(value = "/new", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<SampleAck> add(@RequestBody List<BaseSample> samples) {

    publisher.publish(samples, exchange, routingKey);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new SampleAck(samples.size(), new Date()));

}
```

**So the broker connection is OK but the exchange is not found**

and rabbitmq resources exists

```
xxxxxx@xxxxxxx:~/factory/udc-collector$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_exchanges
Listing exchanges for vhost / ...
name    type
amq.topic   topic
amq.rabbitmq.trace  topic
amq.match   headers
amq.direct  direct
amq.fanout  fanout
    direct
amq.rabbitmq.log    topic
amq.headers headers
samples direct

xxxx@xxxxx:~/factory/udc-collector$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Timeout: 60.0 seconds ...
Listing queues for vhost / ...
name    messages
samples.default 2
```

Any idea ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems quite obvious:

> no exchange '"samples"' in vhost

```
broker.exchange = "samples"
broker.routingKey = "samples.default"
```

Remove the quotes

```
broker.exchange=samples
broker.routingKey=samples.default
```